# set default gcc for mkoctfile

Tags: macos, octave, macports

I have a default compiler on MacOS set to clang. When installing packages for octave (using `pkg install` from the octave prompt), I would like mkoctfile to use the macports gcc48. (In fact, octave itself was built using gcc48).

In other words:

> mkoctfile -p CC

gives me the path to the default clang, and I would like it to point to gcc48. Is there a configuration file for mkoctfile which would allow such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the environment variable `CXX`. You can do this by, running `setenv ("CXX", "your favourite compiler")` before `pkg install` (leave it in your `octave.rc` so it's ran every time), or by running `export CXX=your_favourite_compiler` before starting octave.